# Error while database connection with Qt

Tags: mysql, qt

I was trying with the basic example for connection of database with qt but got the following error after running of the program. The error is as follow:

```
Error ="Driver not loaded"
```

My program was as follows:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString servername = "LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS";
    QString dbname = "test";

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setConnectOptions();
    QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%1;DATABASSE=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;").arg(servername).arg(dbname);

    db.setDatabaseName(dsn);

    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Opened!";
        db.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error =" << db.lastError().text();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Please help me solve by showing me where I went wrong. I am new to this.

Comment: `DATABASSE` - is double S ok in your connection string?

Comment: @Cherry You have spelt 'database' wrong.

Comment: I am not getting actually I am new to this so what should I do to solve the problem.